# Didn't find class “com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider, While upgrading the apk from eclipse with studio build

Tags: java, android, eclipse, firebase

Logs :

> B
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.nova.app.check, PID: 28293 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nova.app.check-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nova.app.check-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5814) at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342) at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.nova.app.check-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.nova.app.check-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]] at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5799) at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403)  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342)  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

===

I have enabled the multidex in gradle, my application class is extends with the MultiDexApplication... I have implemented the support multidex library also.......

Once my application is installed successfully,The application starts to crash.

My build.gradle content

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
//buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nova.app.check"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 17
    versionName "2.0.1"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        jni.srcDirs = []

    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            //minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        release {
            //minifyEnabled true
            //shrinkResources true
            //runProguard false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        staging {
            // Specifies a sorted list of fallback build types that the
            // plugin should try to use when a dependency does not include a
            // "staging" build type. You may specify as many fallbacks as you
            // like, and the plugin selects the first build type that's
            // available in the dependency.
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'qa', 'release']
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        // exclude 'META-INF/json.tld'
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation files('libs/GraphView-3.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jWebSocketClientAPI-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jWebSocketCommon-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jWebSocketJavaSEClient-1.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/json-taglib-0.4.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    implementation files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    implementation files('libs/zip4j_1.3.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/ImageLoader.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/itsrts-pptviewer.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible

    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation project(path: ':androidTest')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    //for qr code scanning
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:12.0.1'
    //implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    // migrate from eclipse
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1'

    implementation files('libs/gcm-server.jar')
    implementation files('libs/OneSignalSDK.jar')

    //socket connection lib for remoteview
    implementation 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.6.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0"
    // custom fab
    implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

    // butter knife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

    //zoom imageView library
    implementation 'com.jsibbold:zoomage:1.1.0'

    //pdfviewer library
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

    // custom images
    //implementation 'com.linsea:universalvideoview:1.1.0@aar'

    //qr code scan
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'

    //testing lib
}
}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0-alpha3'
}
```

> Note : My base application is installed from the eclipse and now >i have upgraded this from the apk generated from studio. My application is a launcher application starts at the boot stage itself.

Comment: Goto: Build -> Clean Project -> Run it again

Comment: Please add the content of your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @GursheeshSingh I have tried clean build and rebuild also.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated my build.gradle file above

Comment: @beginner Have you tried to disable `Instant Run` in Android Studio? `Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run`.

Comment: @beginner Have youalso tried to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of your file?

Comment: @beginner please check below answer hope this may help to you.

Comment: @AlexMamo I didn't tried out this plugin addition, I will check and share the feedback.

Comment: @beginner Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: @AlexMamo One observation: If I restarted the device after installation, everything is working fine without any poblem.

Comment: @beginner Now is everything alright using what I have mentioned above?

Comment: At the time of upgrade, it is crashing continuously and we can't able to do any action in the tablet. we need to reboot it. After rebooting everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck first

```
Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Enable Instant Run
```

Then add this code into your build.gradle in module: app inside defaultConfing:

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    ....
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

Add this code into your build.gradle in module: app  inside dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    .....
    .....
}
```

Open AndroidManifest.xml and within application:

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    .....
    .....
</application>
```

or if you have your Application class, extend it from MultiDexApplication like:

```
 public class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication {
    .....
   }
```

Hope this may help to you

Comment: I have included the same in my project already. 'dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    .....
    .....
}'                                                                           Instead of this library I am using the version of 1.0.3 .